# Dynamically add previous row value to current row value in SQL(Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the following structure:

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 |

I would like to get the following result:

| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 | 3 |
| 4 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 6 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 7 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

where col3= col3 value of previous row + col1 value - col2 value

I added a column of zeroes like this:

| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 7 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

and tried the following query:

```
select col1, col2, 
lag(col3) over (order by id) + col1 - col2 as col3
from t1;
```

However I am not able to obtain the desired result. I would like to get some help with this.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Without a column that specifies the ordering, there is no "previous" row or value.

Comment: there is an 'id' column, updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need analytical function `sum` as follows:

```
select col1, col2, 
       Sum(col1 - col2) over (order by id) as col3
  from t1;
```